# Compare two similar columns in different tables and result in separate output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables with same column names. I would like to compare two columns .
For eg:- 
Table 1 has server and IP address like

```
   Server1   ip1
   comp1    192.168.1.1
   comp2    192.168.1.32
```

Table 2:-

```
  Server2    ip2
  comp3     192.168.1.1
  comp2     192.168.1.33
  comp4     192.168.1.42
  comp5     192.168.1.43
```

Desired output:-

```
server1  ip1            server2      ip2         iserverchange isipchange
comp1    192.168.1.1    comp3     192.168.1.1       Yes          No
comp2    192.168.1.32   comp2     192.168.1.33      No           Yes               
null     null           comp5     192.168.1.43      No           No
null     null           comp4     192.168.1.42      No           No
```

Comment: are you asking how joins work in sql? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp. For all the flags you can do something like table1.ip = table2.ip as isipchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a `FULL JOIN` is what you need here.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (Server1 varchar(50), ip1 varchar(50));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (Server2 varchar(50), ip2 varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
('comp1', '192.168.1.1'),
('comp2', '192.168.1.32');

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
('comp3', '192.168.1.1'),
('comp2', '192.168.1.33'),
('comp4', '192.168.1.42'),
('comp5', '192.168.1.43');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    T1.Server1
    ,T1.ip1
    ,T2.Server2
    ,T2.ip2
    ,CASE WHEN T1.Server1 <> T2.Server2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS iserverchange
    ,CASE WHEN T1.ip1 <> T2.ip2 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS isipchange
FROM
    @T1 AS T1
    FULL JOIN @T2 AS T2
        ON T1.Server1 = T2.Server2
        OR T1.ip1 = T2.ip2
;
```

**Result**

```
| Server1 | ip1          | Server2 | ip2          | iserverchange | isipchange |
|---------|--------------|---------|--------------|---------------|------------|
| comp1   | 192.168.1.1  | comp3   | 192.168.1.1  | Yes           | No         |
| comp2   | 192.168.1.32 | comp2   | 192.168.1.33 | No            | Yes        |
| NULL    | NULL         | comp4   | 192.168.1.42 | No            | No         |
| NULL    | NULL         | comp5   | 192.168.1.43 | No            | No         |
```

Comment: . . It looks like a `LEFT JOIN` to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this query with simple `join`s

```
select t1.server server1,
       t1.ip ip1, 
       t2.server server2,
       t2.ip ip2, 
       'no' iserverchange,
       'yes' isipchange
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.server = t2.server and t1.ip <> t2.ip

union all

select t1.server server1,
       t1.ip ip1, 
       t2.server server2,
       t2.ip ip2, 
       'yes' iserverchange,
       'no' isipchange
from Table1 t1
join Table2 t2 on t1.server <> t2.server and t1.ip = t2.ip
```

To append server and IPs without a match, you could use below query:

```
SELECT server, ip, null, null, 'no', 'no' FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.server = t1.server
                  AND t2.ip = t1.ip )

UNION ALL

SELECT null, null, server, ip, 'no', 'no' FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1
                  WHERE t2.server = t1.server
                  AND t2.ip = t1.ip )
```

Comment: Michal I have a problem what if rows are more than another table. eg:- table 2 few more rows like comp4 192.168.1.42, comp5 192.168.1.43, comp6 192.168.1.44. after adding these columns results arenot good.

Comment: @PhanindraPothuri Please update your question, include this sample data and show what is desired output in that case.

Comment: @downvoter If the reason of downvote was a change to OP requirements, I update answer to match them.